# Can Puppet install a command to be used later by a custom resource?

Tags: puppet

I have a custom resource written in Ruby, whose provider uses a command. The command comes from an RPM package which I would also like Puppet to install. Even with what I believe are the right dependencies, this doesn't work, because the `command` method is evaluated while the catalogue is being compiled, before any resources have run. At least, that's my understanding.

Is there a way to make this work? In an agentless setup I could just run two separate manifests, but how will it work with Puppet Server?

Comment: Can you show the debug logs and preferably provider code? This should work, from what I remember and from a quick test. You should see "file /usr/bin/example does not exist" debug during the run which should stop when the command becomes available. Catalog compilation should never be affected by provider availability either, it's purely agent-side during evaluation.

Comment: Having looked at the code that installed the dependent package, there's no way it would have worked! But the debug output does show it trying, which proves your point. So feel free to answer "This works if you do it properly" and I'll accept :-)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provides using the `commands` directive (e.g. `commands :foo => '/usr/bin/foo'`) should automatically start being used for resources when the file exists, if no other working provider was found.

`commands` generates a "confine" directive internally, confining the provider to only run when the file exists. Similar ones are for "features", e.g. requiring that a certain Ruby library ("feature") is loaded. All of these should be continually re-evaluated by the Puppet agent for a provider when resources exist in the catalog that have no other working provider.

You'll see messages such as this on the agent when run with `--debug`:

```
Debug: Puppet::Type::Example::ProviderExample: file /usr/bin/foo does not exist
```

Once the file appears, the messages should stop and any resources using the provider should run. If the file doesn't appear, this message will appear towards the end of the agent run:

```
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for example
```

Catalogs should always compile on the master before providers are considered, and the agent should attempt to run as much as it can before failing those resources.

As you noted, "this works if you do it properly"!